# Save edited image to Camera Roll

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna, stream

I am new to C# and learning to develop for Windows Phone 8. I am making an image editing app. **Is there a way to save edited image in camera roll instead of saved pictures.**

using PhotoChooserTask returns a PhotoResult.

```
    private WriteableBitmap _imageBitmap = null;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PhotoChooserTask chooser = new PhotoChooserTask();
        chooser.Completed += choosenImage;
        chooser.Show();
    }

    private void choosenImage(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK ) { return; }
        _imageBitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        dummyImage.Source = _thumbImageBitmap;

        //MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
        //library.SavePictureToCameraRoll(String, Stream);
    }
```

I want to save this PhotoResult(image) in the Camera Roll. I did a little bit of research and found

> [MediaLibrary.SavePictureToCameraRoll Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.savepicturetocameraroll%28v=xnagamestudio.42%29.aspx)

This method helps to

```
MediaLibrary.SavePictureToCameraRoll (String, Stream)
Save the specified image Stream as a Picture in the Windows Phone camera roll.
```

OR

```
MediaLibrary.SavePictureToCameraRoll (String, Byte[])
Save the specified byte array as a Picture in the Windows Phone camera roll.
```

How do I implement this method in my code?

Answer (score 0):

`e.ChosenPhoto` is already a stream, so you can just set it like so:

EDIT: This should fix the issue with using the stream twice. You may be able to simply seek to the start of the stream and reuse `e.ChosenPhoto`, but I can't test that until I get home.

```
private void choosenImage(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK ) 
    { 
        return;
    }
    Stream theCopy = new Stream();
    e.ChosenPhoto.CopyTo(theCopy);
    e.ChosenPhoto.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );

    _imageBitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
    dummyImage.Source = _thumbImageBitmap;

    MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
    library.SavePictureToCameraRoll(String, theCopy);
}
```

Comment: i tried that but it gave me error. 'An exception of type `System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll but was not handled in user code. 
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued`............ My code = `library.SavePictureToCameraRoll("image.jpg", e.ChosenPhoto)`;

Comment: I've updated this with a few extra calls that will likely fix that issue.